# Use latest version of Docker image for app platform (deploy latest using Terraform)

Tags: docker, terraform, digital-ocean

I'm using Terraform to deploy to the DigitalOcean App platform which basically works good. I'm deploying a public image from DockerHub.

This is my config.

```
resource "digitalocean_app" "docs-page" {
  spec {
    domain {
      name = "${var.do_subdomain_docs}.${var.do_base_domain}"
    }
    name   = "docs-page"
    region = var.do_region

    service {
      name               = "docs-page-app"
      http_port          = 80
      instance_count     = 1
      instance_size_slug = var.do_instance_smallest
      internal_ports     = []
      source_dir         = "/"

      image {
        registry_type = "DOCKER_HUB"
        registry      = "sommerfeldio"
        repository    = "docs-website"
        tag           = "stable"
      }

      routes {
        path                 = "/"
        preserve_path_prefix = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The image of choice is my sommerfeldio/docs-website:stable (`docker pull sommerfeldio/docs-website:stable`).

My problem is this: I deploy a new version of my image to DockerHub. Then I trigger `terraform apply` to update my DigitalOcean infrastructure and terraform states, that nothing has changed ("Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed."). This might be true from an infrastructure-pount-of-view because there is no chagne to e.g. the instances count or domain name or whatever. But my image did change. And this change is not picked up. To update my DigitalOcean app I have to destroy and re-provision everything. Which is not something I wanna do.

I'm using this provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs

How can I tell the terraform-digitalocean-provider to (1) re-deploy the app with the latest image version from DockerHub or (2) update my above mentioned config in a way that it is mandatory to load the image from DockerHub all the time?

Comment: You could use the Docker provider and when reference it somehwo in the image block in the `digitalocean_app` resource.

Comment: For example: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs/resources/image.

Comment: The Docker provider doesn't do the trick. Pulling the latest image to my local machine with the works but does not integrate with digitalocean_provider. The digitalocean_provider downloads the Docker image from DockerHub directly to DigitalOcean and doesn't care for images on my machine. What I'd like to do (ideally) is force the digitalocean_provider to recognize changes to the images sha256_digest and update the app the next time I run `terraform apply`.

Comment: Second possibility would be to force the digitalocean_provider to always download the image from DockerHub no matter what changes took place at DockerHub. Just always download.